# LESS Mixin Bug on :after Pseudo Selector

Tags: less

I just found out a weird situation.
It seems that there's a bug on :after pseudo selector

Please check the following code, and see the inline comments

```
.nav-prev a{
    left:20px;
    &:before {
        top: 75%;
        .chevron-line;
        .rotate ();
    }
    // this mixin is causing an error and it wouldn't compile
    &:after {
        top: 25%;
        .chevron-line;
        .rotate (-45deg);
    }​
}

// // this is the fix applied for the previous error
// .nav-prev a:after {
//  top: 25%;
//  .chevron-line;
//  .rotate (-45deg);
// }​

.nav-next a{
    right:20px;
    &:before{
        top: 25%;
        .chevron-line;
        .rotate ();
    }
    // strangely this one works and compile correctly
    &:after{
        top: 75%;
        .chevron-line;
        .rotate (-45deg);
    }
}
```

Note : I use LiveReload for compiling.

**Question**

What's wrong with my syntax?
Or is it a LESS bug?
Or is it a compiler bug?

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I copied and pasted your problem code into [this compiler](http://less2css.org/) there is a hidden character showing up that caused an error for me. This character is *not present* in the working code for `.nav-next a` given above, so it likely is the culprit.

```
.nav-prev a{
    left:20px;
    &:before {
        top: 75%;
        .chevron-line;
        .rotate ();
    }
    // this mixin is causing an error and it wouldn't compile
    &:after {
        top: 25%;
        .chevron-line;
        .rotate (-45deg);
    }​<--HIDDEN "DOT" CHARACTER SHOWING UP RIGHT HERE
}
```